# How to set screen resolution in unity and then scale to fit window size

Tags: unity-game-engine

Trying to get Gameboy resolution which is 160px x 144px in unity and then the game will scale up when in full screan with bars around the side where the aspect ratio doesn't fit. But it still only has 160 "pixels" just scaled to take up however many pixels it takes

Answer (score 0):

You could start by reading the documentation file on "Resolution and Presentation"

here is the link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#Resolution

and this forum page also seems to be helpful:https://forum.unity.com/threads/target-dpi-vs-render-scale-vs-resolution-scaling-fixed-dpi-factor-vs-setresolution.1076789/

Now based on these two I would consider this to be your solution:

Go to **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Player** (on the left list) > **Resolution and Presentation**

once you are here find the **Resolution Scaling Mode** option and set it to **Fixed DPI** as shown [in this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLy0P.png)

Once you do that you get the option to choose a number between **30** to **1000**, which you would decide based on the output screen you target. If the number you set is lower than the screens native dpi, your game will upscale and by the same reasoning, I would say it would downscale if you set it higher than the native dpi of the target screen. I am not 100% sure this is the solution to your problem, but I hope it sets you up on the right direction.

Comment: I think that is only for mobile. I don't see that option in my settings. https://ibb.co/20JhcCW

Comment: @FinnM What happens if you set the Fullscreen mode to Exclusice Fullscreen?
you can check out the specific documentation here 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/playersettings-windows.html#Resolution